# integrated with JQGrid not loading data into custome edit JQForm

Tags: php, jqgrid

I am trying to integrate jqgrid and jqform but the data is not being populated into my jqform. I tested to make sure the jqgrid is passing over search key value for the form, and that works. But for some reason, my reform will not query correctly and populate form objects.

```
  <?php 
        if(!isset($_SESSION))
                session_start();

            // Include class  
        include_once 'jqformconfig.php'; 
            if(!class_exists('jqGridUtils'))
            {   
            include_once $CODE_PATH.'jqUtils.php';
            }  
        include_once $CODE_PATH.'jqForm.php';  

            $today = getdate(time());
            $displayDate = $today['mon']."/".$today['mday']."/".$today['year'].'  '.$today['hours'].':'.$today['minutes'].':'.$today['seconds'];
            $machrecs = null;

        // Create instance  
        $newForm = new jqForm('MWOForm',array('action' => 'forms/mwoForm.php', 'method' => 'post', 'id' => 'MWOForm')); 

        // Demo Mode creating connection  
            if(!class_exists('jqGridDB'))
            {
                include_once $CODE_PATH.'/jqGridPdo.php';
            }  
        $conn = new PDO(DB_DSN, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD); 
        $conn->query("SET NAMES utf8");
        $newForm->setConnection( $conn ); 

        // Set url 
        $newForm->setUrl($SERVER_HOST.$SELF_PATH.'forms/mwoForm.php'); 

        // Set parameters  
        $mwo_id = jqGridUtils::GetParam('mwo_id',0901270825);
        $mwo_id = is_numeric($mwo_id) ? (int)$mwo_id : 0; 
        $jqformparams = array($mwo_id); 

        // Set SQL Command, table, keys  
        $newForm->SelectCommand = 'SELECT mwo_id, asset_id, short_desc as machDesc 
                                                             FROM mfg_eng_mwo.mwo 
                                                                 WHERE mwo_id =?';

          $newForm->table = 'mfg_eng_mwo.mwo'; 
        $newForm->setPrimaryKeys('mwo_id'); 
        $newForm->serialKey = true; 

        // Set Form layout  
        $newForm->setColumnLayout('twocolumn'); 
        $newForm->setTableStyles('width:500px;','','');

            $statusSQL =   'SELECT distinct type FROM mfg_eng_mwo.wo_status';
            $prioritySQL = 'SELECT distinct type FROM mfg_eng_mwo.wo_priority';
            $deptSQL =     'SELECT dept_id FROM mfg_eng_mwo.department';

            $deptData = '-1:Select a Department';
        $machData = "";
        $assetData = "";
        $postData = "";

            if(isset($row))
            {
            $deptData = "$row[dept]:$row[dept]";
            $machData = "$row[asset_no]:$row[machDesc]";
            $assetData =$row['asset_no'];
            $postData = $row['post'];
            }

            $parts = '-:Order Parts?;1:YES;0:NO';
            $tools = '-:Order Tools?;1:YES;0:NO';

        // Add elements         
            $newForm->addElement('woStatus',   'select',   array('label' => '<b>Status</b>',            'datasql' => $statusSQL, 'id' => 'woStatus', 'required'=>true));
        $newForm->addElement('WOPriority', 'select',   array('label' => '<b>Priority</b>',          'datasql' => $prioritySQL, 'id' => 'woPriority'));
            $newForm->addElement('dept',       'select',   array('label' => '<b>Deptartment</b>',       'datalist' => $deptData,  'datasql' => $deptSQL, 'id' => 'dept', 'required'=>true));        
        $newForm->addElement('machDesc',   'select',   array('label' => '<b>Machine Desc</b>',      'datalist' => $machData, 'id' => 'machDesc','required'=>true));
            $newForm->addElement('asset_id',   'text',     array('label' => '<b>Asset ID#</b>',         'value' => $assetData, 'size' => '20', 'id' => 'MWOForm_asset_id', 'readonly'=>true, 'required'=>true));        
            $newForm->addElement('post',       'text',     array('label' => '<b>Post</b>',              'value' => $postData, 'maxlength' => '40', 'id' => 'post', 'readonly'=>true, 'required'=>true));
            $newForm->addElement('requester',  'text',     array('label' => '<b>Requester</b>',         'value' => $_SESSION['user'], 'maxlength' => '60',  'id' => 'requester', 'readonly'=>true, 'required'=>true));
        $newForm->addElement('enterTime',  'text',     array('label' => '<b>Created</b>',           'value' => $displayDate, 'maxlength' => '15', 'size' => '20', 'id' => 'enterTime', 'readonly'=>true,'required'=>true));
        //$newForm->addElement('short_desc', 'text',     array('label' => '<b>Short Description</b>', 'maxlength' => '15', 'size' => '20', 'id' => 'short_desc', 'required'=>true));
            //$newForm->addElement('parts',      'select',   array('label' => '<b>Parts Needed</b>',      'datalist' =>     $parts, 'id' => 'parts', 'required' => 'true', 'hidden' => 'true'));
            //$newForm->addElement('tools',      'select',   array('label' => '<b>Tools</b>',             'datalist' => $tools, 'id' => 'tools', 'hidden' => 'true'));
        $newForm->addElement('problem',    'textarea', array('label' => '<b>Problem</b>', 'rows' => "3", 'cols' => "50", 'id' => 'problem', 'required'=>true));
        $newForm->addElement('solution',   'textarea', array('label' => '<b>Solution</b>', 'rows' => "3", 'cols' => "50", 'id' => 'solution'));
            $elem_8[]=$newForm->createElement('newSubmit','submit', array('value' => 'Submit')); 
        $newForm->addGroup("newGroup",$elem_8, array('style' => 'text-align:right;', 'id' => 'newForm_newGroup'));

    // Add events
    $onchangeDept = <<< CHANGEDEPT
    function(event) 
    {
      $("#machDesc").show();    
        var deptval =  $("#dept").val();    
        jQuery.ajax(
        { 
          url: 'machine.php', 
          dataType: 'json', 
          data: {q:deptval}, 
          success : function(response) 
          {                                     
                 $('#machDesc').find('option').remove();    
                     $('#machDesc').append('<option value=-1>Select Equipment</option>');                                     
                 jQuery.each(response, function(i,mach) 
                 { 
                  $('#machDesc').append('<option value='+mach.asset_no+'>'+mach.asset_no+'::'+mach.short_desc+'</option>');                         
             });
                     $('#asset_no').val('');                          
             $('#post').val('');                     
          }             
       });      
    }
    CHANGEDEPT;
    $newForm->addEvent('dept','change',$onchangeDept);

    $onchangeMach = <<< CHANGEMACH
    function(event) 
    {       
      var assetval = $("#machDesc").val();  
        jQuery.ajax(
        { 
                url: 'post.php', 
          dataType: 'json', 
          data: {q:assetval},               
          success : function(response) 
          {                                                                           
                 jQuery.each(response, function(i,mach) 
                 {
                      $('#MWOForm_asset_id').val(mach.asset_no); 
                $('#post').val(mach.post);                          
           });

          } 
       });      
    }
    CHANGEMACH;
    $newForm->addEvent('machDesc','change',$onchangeMach);

    $beforeSubmit = <<< BS
    function(arr, form, options) 
    {  
        var toolval =  $("#tool").val();
        var partval =  $("#part").val();

      if(toolval == 0 || toolval == 1) 
      { 
        alert("Please select 'YES' or 'NO' for tools."); 
        return false; 
      } 
        if(partval != 1 || partval != 0) 
      { 
        alert("Please select YES or NO for tools."); 
        return false; 
      }
    } 
    BS;

    // Add events
    $onclicknewButton = <<< CLICKNEWBUTTON
    function(event) 
    {
      if($("#ajax-dialog") ) {
        $("#ajax-dialog").remove();
      }
    }
    CLICKNEWBUTTON;
    $newForm->addEvent('close_modal','click',$onclicknewButton);
    // Add ajax submit events
    $success = <<< SU
    function( response, status, xhr) {
    if(response=='success')
    {
      $("#grid").trigger("reloadGrid", [{current:true}]);
    }
    }
    SU;


    // Add ajax submit events 
    $newForm->setAjaxOptions( array('dataType'=>null, 
                                    'resetForm' =>false,
                                                                    'clearForm' =>false,
                                                                    'success' =>'js:'.$success,
                                                                    'beforeSubmit' =>'js:'.$beforeSubmit,
                                                                    'iframe' => false,
                                                                    'forceSync' =>false) ); 

    // Render the form  
    echo $newForm->renderForm($jqformparams);

    ?>
    </body>
```

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Maintenance Work Order System</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="themes/redmond/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="themes/ui.jqgrid.css" />
    
    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

Comment: I am trying to use jqGrid integrated with jqForm, but the form is not populating.  
1. I have checked to make sure that the grid is passing over data to the jqForm and it is. So the value ‘mwo_id’ is being populated.  $mwo_id = jqGridUtils::GetParam('mwo_id',0901270825);
2. I have checked the query to make sure there are no issue with it syntactically and it returns a query result.